# Which is the best way to perform CRUD operations on firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it better to create cloud functions, that are called from within your flutter app, that perform operations(Create Read Update Delete) on your cloud firestore or is it better to just directly access your firestore using flutter without the intervention of any cloud function? What are the ideal situations that determine which method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the documents that you are working with. As long as you specified the security rules for specific document paths and all the data is validated within the app and in the security rules, you should be fine to complete these operations from the app. It is also important to give access to only authenticated users, you can implement firebase_auth plugin for that.

[You can check-out this video to understand the security rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw)

If you are performing anything else than CRUD, like managing notifications or dynamically changing the documents in the background - that's where you can get the most out of Cloud Functions. Firebase team also has great videos about it.